# Spring MVC: @ManyToMany DAO?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, many-to-many, dao

In my application, i'm attemping to create a many-to-many relation with additional fields
following this tutorial:

[hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/)

I would like to know what the best practice says about where to put DAO methods related to this relationship.

**is it better to create a dao specific for the association (ex. StockCategoryDAO) or put the methods in the StockDAO / Category ?**

For example, I get confused thinking about that:

ex.1 - a method which gives me all Stocks associated to a category... 
i don't need that because i already have **getter** in Category model class... right?

ex.2 - i will have a page under the Stock panel, where i will select (checkboxes) which categories
are associated to this stock (the stock already exists in db). 
After submit, in the controller i get all selected checkboxes (if you know an examples how to this, you are welcome) and i have to call a service method (which encapsulates my dao) to insert
the association.
 In this case is it better to use the setter of Stock class, followed by a `session.update(stock)`  or use a StockCategoryService.addCategoryService(...) for each category selected?

thanks for any advices

Comment: The relationship class is a good pattern that will probably save you from other headaches, such as where to hold and reference the relationship specific metadata (the additional fields you mention). If there are fields associated with the relationship, then they don't belong on the objects on either side of the relationship, the belong to the relationship itself, and so this needs to be represented in some way in java. Meaning that you don't really have a many-to-many, you actually have a many-to-one-to-many relationship.

Comment: in the tutorial is shown how to write a model class for every entity and for many-to-one-to-many entity classes. but my question was focused on dao classes. btw your comment helped me to understand better many-to-many relationship. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the basic design should be "Every Model class should have its own DAO class that has all the methods defined, that operate on that particular model". This includes all getters too.

DAO methods are based on model.

So, you need to put all the getter methods for the Stock in the StockDAO class.

And you can define the RowMapper class as a inner class in the DAO class, if you are using jdbctemplate and if you want to return custom objects

I would suggest you to use JdbcTemplate class. This minimizes the code in DAO class.

Here I have listed the steps to carry out this implementation:

1. Declare the JdbcTemplate bean in spring.xml and inject the datasource bean as property o jdbcTemplate bean

(So during initialization itself JdbcTemplate is created with right datasurce)

1. Implement DAO class for every model. Define all the methods (including getters) inside the DAO class.
2. if your getter method returns custom object, implement rowMapper class as inner class in the DAO class.
   (implementing rowMapper gives jdbcTemplate, a sense about the resultset)

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. For clear code and good organization, i think too it's better write a DAO for every model. btw i'm using hibernate, so i think jdbcTemplate is not for me... right?

Comment: Yes, that's right! For hibernate, you can use HibernateDAO Support classes

Comment: i'm having a big big trouble making a form with checkboxes for this many to many relationship.. i wrote a question about this.. if someone could take a look i would be very very happy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633603/form-with-checboxes-for-a-many-to-many-relationship-spring-mvc-webflow-thyme